# Euler Totient Issues

Tags: abstract-algebra, analytic-number-theory, totient-function

I was skimming again through Dummit & Foote's *Abstract Algebra* and I came across this exercise:

Prove that for any given positive integer $N$ there exist only finitely many integers $n$ with $\varphi(n)=N$, where $\varphi$ denotes Euler $\varphi$-function. Conclude in particular that $\varphi(n)$ tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity.

I don't doubt that $\varphi(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. However, if I recall Erdös proved that if there is an $x_0$ such that $\varphi(x_0)=N$, then there must be infinitely many integers such that $\varphi(x)=N$. See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientValenceFunction.html) article for a mention of this (it's in the very first $2$ lines).

Am I reading something wrong here? Has has Dummit and Foote actually asked the impossible? Or does the MathWorld site contain an error?

Comment: The link doesn't say quite what you think it does -- there are infinitely many integers with the same multiplicity, not infinitely many with the same solution to $\varphi (n) = N$.

Comment: @Marc & André: I knew it was something obvious but I stared at this for a good half hour not seeing it. I guess it's just one of those nights. Thank you both for pointing out what I should have seen!

Comment: The phrasing could have been better, so don't feel bad.

Comment: Note that $$  \varphi(n) \geq \sqrt {\frac{n}{2}},  $$ for an easy example of a lower bound showing that $\varphi(n)$ tends to infinity. Also $$  \varphi(n) \geq \; 2 \; \left( \frac{n}{6} \right)^{2/3},  $$

Comment: FYI, I have given a proof [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380705/if-n-j-p-1-cdot-ldots-cdot-p-t-fracp-1-cdot-ldots-cdot-p-tp-j-th/380758#380758).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you refer to does not say what you think it does. What it says is that if there is an $m_0$ such that $\varphi(x)=m_0$ has exactly $k$ solutions, then there exist infinitely many $m$ such that $\varphi(x)=m$ has exactly $k$ solutions.

For example, let $k=3$. There is an $m_0$, namely $2$, such that $\varphi(x)=m_0$ has exactly $k$ solutions. These are $3$, $4$, and $6$. We can conclude that there are infinitely many $m$ such that $\varphi(x)=m$ has exactly $3$ solutions.

Comment: I knew it was something obvious but I stared at this for a good half hour not seeing it. I guess it's just one of those nights. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. One of these nights happens to all of us.